# First page of crystal report data s getting out of box.

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in my visual studio project. I designed like this:

[image]

now I am getting result which is not proper.
i am getting my report like this:
[image]

I mean on first page some data is getting out of my BOX. Rest of all page it is coming proper.
In my first page of crystal report my data is coming like that. If any know how to solve this issue please help me to find out.

Comment: Try setting the Can Grow Property of the text object and this can be solved, it will enable wrapping of the text.

Comment: i want to set to all text object

Comment: Mam..i setted all text object can grow property as tru.but stil am getting data out of box in first page

Comment: Are you talking about the date on the lower left?

Comment: yes,,u can see three rows came after my BOX..u can easily find out,,the data under 09-jul-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the "Can Grow" property to the field that gets cut off. The one drawback is that your grid line may need to be moved so the text doesn't spill over the line.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:
Since we now know what the issue is, here is another suggestion:
Drawing boxes and lines is very difficult in Crystal. If you don't put them exactly in the right spot they won't draw correctly. So make sure that none of your boxes spill over into other sections. Also, you can right-click on the box and click "Format Box" and check the "Extend to Bottom of Section When Printing", which will ensure that the box prints correctly. But most likely your box extends into a section above and that's why it's not showing correctly. Make the box smaller than it needs to be so you are sure it's only in the section you want it to be. Check to see if it shows up correctly and then slowly make it the size you want it to be.

Comment: sir,,i already set can grow property of all text object..but stil am getting data out of box in first page

Comment: Are you talking about the date in the lower left corner between your details and the totals?

Comment: yes,,u can see three rows came after my BOX..u can easily find out,,the data under 09-jul-2013

Comment: So you want to have the date and the other three lines in your box? Did you draw the lines of the box manually?

Comment: Please see my revised answer

Comment: sir i right clicked on box..but that is showing only line property

Comment: If you right-click on the box you should get a pop-up with "Format Box", "Format Painter", "Size and Position", etc. But I think your issue is the position of the box.

Comment: Move your box to the top of section 2